# overflow hidden and scrolling no not working in embed

Tags: scroll, overflow, embed

I am unable to hide scrolling in embed. i also try to this by two methods,-

Method 1:

```
<embed scrolling="no" src="http://www.pjsindia.com"style="background-color: #55A97C;" width="400px" height="400px"></embed>
```

Method 2:

```
<embed src="http://www.pjsindia.com"style="background-color: #55A97C; overflow:hidden;" width="400px" height="400px"></embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overflow: auto

It may work in some browsers but not guaranteed to work in all browsers. You should test it in all browsers.